# Query DB to show count of records done in the morning and the afternoon

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table (walkin2012) with the following fields:

```
ID |    date    |    store   | timestamp            | custName
1  | 2013-05-08 | Plainfield | 2013-05-08 10:38:40  | cust1
2  | 2013-05-08 | Plainfield | 2013-05-08 13:38:40  | cust2
3  | 2013-05-09 | Bayport    | 2013-05-09 20:38:40  | cust3
4  | 2013-05-10 | Plainfield | 2013-05-10 17:38:40  | cust4
5  | 2013-05-10 | Bayport    | 2013-05-10 11:38:40  | cust4
```

I would like to query the table to show the number of record done between 10AM-1PM as Morning and anything after as Afternoon per date per store so that it will simply give me this result:

```
date       | store      | morning | afternoon
2013-05-08 | Plainfield | 1       | 1
2013-05-09 | Bayport    | 0       | 1
2013-05-10 | Bayport    | 1       | 0
2013-05-10 | Plainfield | 0       | 1
```

I got the date,store and morning to work but I'm confused on how to subquery the afternoon part. Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT date, store, count(walkinID) AS Morning 
FROM walkin2012 
WHERE timestamp
BETWEEN concat_ws(' ',date,'10:00:00') AND concat_ws(' ',date,'13:00:00')  
GROUP BY date,store
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: would you please create a fiddle for the same on http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Logical part : `TIME(timestamp column) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('10AM','%l%p') AND STR_TO_DATE('1PM','%l%p') ) as Morning`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  date, 
        store, 
        SUM(timestamp BETWEEN date + interval 10 hour AND 
                              date + interval 13 hour) Morning,
        SUM(timestamp BETWEEN date + interval 13 hour AND 
                              date + interval 24 hour) Afternoon
FROM    walkin2012   
GROUP   BY date, store
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e51f/9)

Comment: if the sale is at 830 in the morning it wont work but otherwise awesome

Comment: tip: wrap `timestamp` column with `\``

Comment: @DrewPierce the problem says `10AM-1PM` and `1PM` onwards :)

Comment: @diEcho `timestamp` is a reserved keyword but it is one of permitted keywords to be used without backtick.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
SELECT a.date, a.store, sum(Morning) as Morning, sum(afternoon) as afternoon FROM (
  SELECT date, store, count(walkinID) AS Morning , 0 AS Afternoon
  FROM walkin2012 
  WHERE timestamp
  BETWEEN concat_ws(' ',date,'10:00:00') AND concat_ws(' ',date,'13:00:00')  
  GROUP BY date,store
  UNION
  SELECT date, store, 0 AS Morning, count(walkinID) AS Afternoon
  FROM walkin2012 
  WHERE timestamp
  < concat_ws(' ',date,'10:00:00') OR timestamp > concat_ws(' ',date,'13:00:00')  
  GROUP BY date,store
) a
GROUP BY a.date, a.store
```